# Ajax request return wrong data in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

My code makes an Ajax request when clicking a button.

On the first click it returns right result from the requested file.
But on the second click on the same button, I get the homepage as result of request.
This script works in Chrome, Opera, and even in IE, but not in Firefox.
Tested on Firefox 30.0 and 31.0

```
function _ajax_baget_page() {
  var uw_calc = + $('#edit_data input[name="uw"]').val();
  var uh_calc = + $('#edit_data input[name="uh"]').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'images/file.php',
    data: 'width=' + uw_calc + '&height=' + uh_calc + '&slice=' + slice_num_calc + '&hv=' + hv_calc,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
      $('#frames').html(html);
    }
  });
};
```

Have any ideas?

Comment: `console.log(html);` and post the response.

Comment: Have you put in some console.log statements and checked the output? I typically test in Chrome's Javascript Console. Try putting them after your var declarations to see what those values are and another after the success to test the html variable returned from your call.

Comment: I found the place of error. It was empty attribute SRC in img tag. This tag is used for fancybox image. But it's wonder me, because the same script is working on other page.